# Liferay Login Log of Live Users

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

How to get liferay login concurrent user's log to find how many users online at a time?

How to maintain user's activity log?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085553/how-to-get-all-logged-in-users-list-in-liferay) of you? What is the difference in your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just see live users. If portlets are custom you can put log in your code for seeing activities, but if you want liferay's portlets activities, it will need lot of changes in code. 
For seeing user, first of all add the following in portal-ext.properties. It is set false in portal-properties.

**live.users.enabled=true**

Now you can see users who are currently live on server in *Control Panel's Monitoring menu*.

Comment: When adding this setting, we can’t log into the portal at all any more: wrong passwords still give an error message, but with the correct password, one is shown the login page again :(