# How to get all logged in users list in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to get all users login detail as Administrator in liferay.
**User login from where is doesn't matter but i want to see list of all users which are login at a time.**
when user login it will send some identification to admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control Panel's **Monitoring** option allows you to see all of the live sessions in the portal.

For performance reasons, this setting is generally turned off in production.
To enable display of live session data, set the portal property **live.users.enabled** to true.

Comment: When adding this setting, we can’t log into the portal at all any more: wrong passwords still give an error message, but with the correct password, one is shown the login page again :(